# How to create test user for In app purchase in new iTuneconnect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, authentication, in-app-purchase

I have create one test user in itune connect. User created successfully. and also able to login in phone apple store. But when I am going to test in app purchase with the same user I am not able to test. It always show the error "The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again". I don't know why this error occur. My provision profile and bundle id are the same for my application and also getting all product list which is register for in app purchase.

Please tell me if any new point still remain in new itune connect.

Comment: from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html): '**Important**: Don’t enter your test account information in the Store settings panel. Doing so may invalidate your test account.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. As my password and email was correct but it was showing the error:

> The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was
>   incorrect. Please try again.

I solved this by adding new sandbox tester  on **iTunes**.

When you visit **iTunes**, and go for  **myApps**. On **myApps** page, on the top left of page there's a drop down menu naming **myApps**. Click for drop down menu. There you will find **Users and Roles** tab.

Click on that and then you will find sandbox tester. Here you can add new sandbox testing user.

Comment: You are right. I was creating test user at wrong place.

Comment: I have been searching all day and this is the only question that has fixed my problem. I was also creating a "`test user`" instead of a "`sandbox Tester`". Thank you.

Comment: Thanks bro! You saved my day.