# Apple ID not found - In-App Purchase iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios8, in-app-purchase

I'm at the stage of testing an "in app purchase" on my iPhone 6+ running 8.1.3.

Basically, you click the "no ads" button which takes you to a new ViewController which handles buying and restoring the purchase.

I followed Geeky Lemons tutorial on Youtube.

For some reason, every time I press "buy", and it prompts me to log in, it tells me "The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found..." even though I'm using a "Test User" created in iTunes Connect.

I've been everywhere and checked several times the common mistakes, including the correct Bundle ID etc, but still nothing.

Below is my `.m` followed by my `console` print outs. As you can see everything works as it should (I think) up until the signing in... I just can't get any futher...

**PurchasedViewController:**

```
#import "PurchasedViewController.h"

@interface PurchasedViewController ()

@end

@implementation PurchasedViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _buyButton.enabled = NO;

    NSLog(@"Default ID: %@", self.productID);
    self.productID = @"My IAP ID";
    NSLog(@"Assigned ID: %@", self.productID);
    [self getProductID];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)BuyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    NSLog(@"Buy Button Pressed...");
}

- (IBAction)Restore:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    NSLog(@"Restore Button Pressed...");
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue{
    [self UnlockPurchase];
}

-(void)getProductID{

    NSLog(@"getProductID Called, ID is: %@", self.productID);

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
        NSLog(@"request started...");
    }
    else{
        _productDescription.text = @"Please enable in app purchasing in your settings";
        NSLog(@"can't make payment...");
    }
}

-(void)UnlockPurchase{
    _buyButton.enabled = NO;
    [_buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    NSLog(@"Unlocking purchase...");
    [self Purchased];
}

-(void)Purchased{
    Label.text = @"Has Now Been Purchased";
    NSLog(@"Updating label...");
}

#pragma mark _
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{    

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if(products.count !=0){
        _product = products[0];
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;


        for (SKProduct *product in products) {
            NSLog(@"Assuming Product Found: %@", product);      //list address of product
        }
    }
    else{
        _productTitle.text = @"Product Not Found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;
    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product Not Found: %@", product);
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: [self UnlockPurchase]; NSLog(@"Transaction Successful...");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed: NSLog(@"Transaction Failed...");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

**NSLogs:**

```
    2015-05-13 03:32:10.433 My App [187:3217] Default ID: (null)
    2015-05-13 03:32:10.434 My App [187:3217] Assigned ID: My IAP ID
    2015-05-13 03:32:10.434 My App [187:3217] getProductID Called, My IAP ID
    2015-05-13 03:32:10.436 My App [187:3217] request started...
    2015-05-13 03:32:13.215 My App [187:3217] Assuming Product Found: <SKProduct: 0x1700190c0>
    2015-05-13 03:32:14.944 My App [187:3217] Buy Button Pressed...
```

I've checked my Bundle ID, product/App ID.
I've cleaned and built the application several times, before and after deleting it from my iPhone, even with reboots.
I've set up 3 test users, all brand new.
My Tax and Banking documents on iTunes Connect etc are approved and valid.
My Banking details are current and valid.
My App is prepared for submission.
My testers are marked as internal testers.
My testers have permission for testflight/beta testing.
The In-App Purchase has been included in the App Purchase section in "My App".
My In-App Purchase status is "Ready To Submit".
I'm signed out of all accounts on my device too.

I've done countless other things and tried nurmeous permuations of all of the above...
What am I missing or not doing?
Please help. Thanks.

**Update**

Just been playing around and changed my Bundle ID out of curiosity, and when the app runs, the `purchasedViewController` doesn't locate the product and prints to the console `Product Not Found: ...`. So everything is linked up from what I can see... It's just unable to validate a Test Apple ID. Please help.

**Another Update**

I've also re-done the whole process, but using [THIS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm) tutorial, which is a slightly different implementation but still, I get the same problem. My Test Apple ID's are never found :(

Comment: Go to your devices Settings>iTunes & App Store>Tap your Apple ID> Logout>Then attempt the IAP in your application.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I'm already `signed out of all accounts on my device`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after many hours of searching the Stack-Exchanges, Google and the Apple Dev Forums, I finally found an answer that helped me... and now I feel really dumb.

Thanks to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049612/how-to-create-test-user-for-in-app-purchase-in-new-ituneconnect) answer here on this Exchange, I've solved my problem and have now successfully purchased my In-App Purchase using a `Test User`.

Basically, I was creating a `Test User` in the wrong place...

Yes, you create a `Test User` in your iTunes Connect account, but you must select "`Sandox Tester`" and not create it in "`iTunes Connect User`" as I was originally doing.

**First** Log into iTunes Connect, and select "Users and Roles":

[image: Select "Users and Roles"]

**Second** Select "Sandbox Testers" and create an In-App Purchase tester here by clicking the "Blue +" button.

[image: Select "Sandbox Testers"]

**Third**

Use the new Sandbox Tester credentials to log into App Store when prompted in your app when testing a purchase. (make sure you're logged out of your usual iTunes account on your device too).

I hope this helps.